# display format of xts when time is 00:00

Tags: r, xts

How can I change the format of the return value of `last` if the time of that time step is 00:00?

Here is an example

I have two `xts` objects containing hourly observations with different end times that I want to align.

```
library(xts)

x <- c(1:10)
dt <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2023-06-14 15:00", tz = "GMT"), by = "hour", length.out = 10)
x <- xts(x, order.by=dt)

y <- c(1:12)
dt <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2023-06-14 15:00", tz = "GMT"), by = "hour", length.out = 12)
y <- xts(y, order.by=dt)
```

If I print `x` I get

```
x
                    [,1]
2023-06-14 15:00:00    1
2023-06-14 16:00:00    2
2023-06-14 17:00:00    3
2023-06-14 18:00:00    4
2023-06-14 19:00:00    5
2023-06-14 20:00:00    6
2023-06-14 21:00:00    7
2023-06-14 22:00:00    8
2023-06-14 23:00:00    9
2023-06-15 00:00:00   10
```

and when printing `y` I get

```
y
                        [,1]
2023-06-14 15:00:00    1
2023-06-14 16:00:00    2
2023-06-14 17:00:00    3
2023-06-14 18:00:00    4
2023-06-14 19:00:00    5
2023-06-14 20:00:00    6
2023-06-14 21:00:00    7
2023-06-14 22:00:00    8
2023-06-14 23:00:00    9
2023-06-15 00:00:00   10
2023-06-15 01:00:00   11
2023-06-15 02:00:00   12
```

This is all good so far. However, if use `last` to determine the end of the time series I get a format of the date without time whereas this is not the case when determine the last entry of `y`:

```
last(index(x)) 
[1] "2023-06-15 GMT"

last(index(y))
[1] "2023-06-15 02:00:00 GMT"
```

If I now do the following, `y` is not subsetted by the extend of `x`, probably because of the time format:

```
y[paste(first(index(x)), last(index(x)), sep="/")]
                        [,1]
2023-06-14 15:00:00    1
2023-06-14 16:00:00    2
2023-06-14 17:00:00    3
2023-06-14 18:00:00    4
2023-06-14 19:00:00    5
2023-06-14 20:00:00    6
2023-06-14 21:00:00    7
2023-06-14 22:00:00    8
2023-06-14 23:00:00    9
2023-06-15 00:00:00   10
2023-06-15 01:00:00   11
2023-06-15 02:00:00   12
```

Comment: Please specify all packages that you are using. I don't know the `eq.POSIXt` function.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `format` and add the timezone like this:

```r
library(xts)

x <- c(1:10)
dt <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2023-06-14 15:00", tz = "GMT"), by = "hour", length.out = 10)
x <- xts(x, order.by=dt)

paste0(format(last(index(x)),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), " GMT")
#> [1] "2023-06-15 00:00:00 GMT"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Note**: the output is a character!

Comment: You can even make use of `%Z` without hardcoding timezone information: `format(last(index(x)), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the `window` function:

```
all.equal(
  y["2023-06-14 15:00:00/2023-06-15 00:00:00"],
  window(y, start = first(index(x)), end = last(index(x)))
)
#[1] TRUE
```

Jumping through hoops to create that character string that needs to be parsed afterwards is really ugly and not R-like.